Separability of $C^k([a,b],X)$ for separable Banach space $X$
Let $(X, \| \cdot \|_X)$ be a separable Banach space. Is the Banach space $C^k([a,b],X)$ with standard norm $\| u \|_{C^k} = \sup_{j \leq k} \| D^j u\|_\infty$ separable? Do you have a reference for it?
Here is a proof sketch. Set $J = [a,b]$.
Separable Metric Space $ Y $: A metric space is separable if it contains a countable dense subset. This means there exists a countable set $D \subset Y$ such that for every point $y \in Y$ and every $ \epsilon > 0 $, there exists a point $ d \in D $ with $ d \in B(y, \epsilon) $ (the open ball of radius $ \epsilon $ centered at $ y $).
To show that $ C^1(J, X) $ is separable, we can employ the following strategy:

Countability of Dense Subsets: Since $ J $ is compact, the space of continuous functions $ C(J, X) $ is separable when $ X $ is separable. Specifically, we can use the fact that $ C(J, X) $ can be approximated by polynomials with rational coefficients (or piecewise linear functions, etc.), which can be made dense in $ C(J, X) $.

Derivatives: The derivatives of functions in $ C^1(J, X) $ also take values in $ X $. Since $ X $ is separable, we can similarly find a countable dense subset in $ C(J, X) $ for the derivatives.

Constructing Dense Sets: We can construct a dense subset of $ C^1(J, X) $ by taking the following steps:

Choose a countable dense subset $ D \subset X $.
For each $ x \in J $, consider a countable dense subset of $ \mathbb{R} $ (like rational numbers).
Construct functions that are piecewise linear (or polynomials) with values in $ D $ and derivatives that also take values in $ D $.


Closure of Dense Sets: The space of functions that are piecewise linear (or polynomials) with rational coefficients can be shown to be dense in $ C^1(J, X) $ under the $ C^1 $ norm, because we can approximate both the function values and their derivatives uniformly.


Thus, combining these points, we conclude that $ C^1(J, X) $ is separable. The key steps involve leveraging the separability of $ X $ and the compactness of $ J $ to construct a countable dense subset in $ C^1(J, X) $.

What have you tried? For example, do you know how to show it for, say, $X = \mathbb{R}^d$, even if just $d=1$? If so, you could tell us what you couldn't adapt from said case, and if not it could be a good starting point to kind of "familiarise" yourself with the problem.

Hi @BrunoB do you have an answer to the problem?

@BrunoB I propose an answer above. The main reason for asking this question is that this must be a known fact. I don't want to reproduce this proof, given that it must be known from textbooks in my opinion. Do you know any reference for that?
